# MYSQL mystery. Value passed to function is incorrect

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

When I submit using this function I get an incorrect result for $_REQUEST["add_single"] in the database of 127, incorrect. but the javascript result is 188, correct. If i replace $_REQUEST["add_single"] with 10 I get 10 inserted into the database.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["add_single"])) {
    save_single_bracelet($_REQUEST["id"], $_REQUEST["add_single"]);

/javascript alert('values:".$_REQUEST["id"].", ".$_REQUEST["add_single"]."'); /script

;}
```

For whatever reason I can not get $_REQUEST["add_single"] to pass the correct value to the function.

J.

Comment: What's the definition of `save_single_bracelet`?

Comment: function save_single_bracelet($watch_id, $bracelet_id) {
 $sql = "INSERT INTO bracelets (watch_id, bracelet_id ) VALUES ('".$watch_id."', '".$bracelet_id."')";
 mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error() . " <br><br>SQL:".$sql);
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column (bracelet_id) wouldn't happen to be of type TINYINT? The maximum value of that data type is 127. You should change it to something more appropiate like INT.

You can view more about data types in MySQL [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)

Comment: If this is the answer, you should vote for the answer and accept it. It would be nice :)

Comment: Thanks, nubie if it's not obvious. Now I know where the button is to select a correct answer. Thanks.